# Integrating Responsive File Manager - icon showing only in the last TinyMCE editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a php page with multiple tinymce editors (textarea) with same classname and seperate id.  My issue is the image upload icon is showing only on the last editor but not in the above editors. I am using tinymce version 4.7.2. 
This is the image upload button i need to show:

[image: image upload button]

[Here is the full image of my php page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6vni.png)

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please edit to include the image in the question.

Comment: ok, i have upload my work image, any doubt please inform me

Comment: Can you create a simple JS Fiddle or TinyMCE Fiddle that shows how you are invoking TinyMCE multiple times on the page?  Without seeing your actual code it will be difficult for anyone to help identify the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hurray i solved i missed a function 'file_picker_callback'

Comment: this link will help 
http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/demo.php 
for those who has stuck in this bug..
then thanx to all who helped me..

Answer (score 0):

`file_picker_callback` will solve the above issue. for ref refer this link http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/demo.php

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#content, textarea#details",theme: "modern",width: 500,height: 200,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code"
   ],
   toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
   toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
   image_advtab: true ,
   file_picker_types:'file image media',
   file_picker_callback:function(cb,value,meta){var width=window.innerWidth-30;var height=window.innerHeight-60;if(width>1800)width=1800;if(height>1200)height=1200;if(width>600){var width_reduce=(width-20)%138;width=width-width_reduce+10;}var urltype=2;if(meta.filetype=='image'){urltype=1;}if(meta.filetype=='media'){urltype=3;}var title="RESPONSIVE FileManager";if(typeof this.settings.filemanager_title!=="undefined"&&this.settings.filemanager_title){title=this.settings.filemanager_title;}var akey="key";if(typeof this.settings.filemanager_access_key!=="undefined"&&this.settings.filemanager_access_key){akey=this.settings.filemanager_access_key;}var sort_by="";if(typeof this.settings.filemanager_sort_by!=="undefined"&&this.settings.filemanager_sort_by){sort_by="&sort_by="+this.settings.filemanager_sort_by;}var descending="false";if(typeof this.settings.filemanager_descending!=="undefined"&&this.settings.filemanager_descending){descending=this.settings.filemanager_descending;}var fldr="";if(typeof this.settings.filemanager_subfolder!=="undefined"&&this.settings.filemanager_subfolder){fldr="&fldr="+this.settings.filemanager_subfolder;}var crossdomain="";if(typeof this.settings.filemanager_crossdomain!=="undefined"&&this.settings.filemanager_crossdomain){crossdomain="&crossdomain=1";if(window.addEventListener){window.addEventListener('message',filemanager_onMessage,false);}else{window.attachEvent('onmessage',filemanager_onMessage);}}tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({title:title,file:this.settings.external_filemanager_path+'dialog.php?type='+urltype+'&descending='+descending+sort_by+fldr+crossdomain+'&lang='+this.settings.language+'&akey='+akey,width:width,height:height,resizable:true,maximizable:true,inline:1},{setUrl:function(url){cb(url);}});},
   external_filemanager_path:"filemanager/",
   filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
   object_resizing : false,
   external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "../../../filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the responsivefilemanager to the toolbar then you dont need the image

```
TinymceModule.withConfig({
  plugins: ['link image code responsivefilemanager'],
  toolbar: 'responsivefilemanager',
  menubar: false,
  external_filemanager_path: '.../filemanager/',
  filemanager_title: 'Content Server',
  filemanager_crossdomain: true,
  external_plugins: {"filemanager": ".../filemanager/plugin.min.js" } 
})
```